# Building a table that counts the frequency that a value appears within the same by group as another value of the same variable

Tags: sas

I have build a table where the headers each column except the first column is a unique `value`, and every cell in the first column is a unique `value` - just the headers but vertical.

| values | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value1 |  |  |  |
| value2 |  |  |  |
| value3 |  |  |  |

I also have a dataset `group`. Every unique `group` can have multiple unique `values`.

| group | value |
| --- | --- |
| group1 | value1 |
| group1 | value2 |
| group1 | value3 |
| group2 | value2 |
| group2 | value3 |
| group2 | value4 |
| group2 | value5 |

I want to see the amount of times every unique `value` appears alongside any other unique `value` that is not itself within the same `group` by populating my first table.

Desired output, given the above example `group` dataset:

| values | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| value2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| value3 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

I have difficulties finding answers as I am not sure what the type of output I want is called. How would I go about achieving my desired results?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can a value appear more than once in a group (n-times)?  If so, would it count n-times when paired with the other values?  If so, the diagonal becomes the total number of times one or more values are repeated in a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a cross-join that counts the number of times each value matches with a different value:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table count_values as
        select t1.value as value_t1
             , t2.value as value_t2
             , count(*) as total
        from have as t1, have as t2
        where     t1.group = t2.group 
              AND t1.value NE t2.value
        group by t1.value, t2.value
    ;
quit;
```

Which gives you this:

```
value_t1    value_t2    total
value1      value2      1
value1      value3      1
value2      value1      1
value2      value3      2
value3      value1      1
value3      value2      2
```

Now we can do a few different things. You can use `proc tabulate` and generate your table:

```
options missing='0';

proc tabulate data   = count_values
              out    = totals 
              format = 8.0;

    class value_t1 value_t2;
    var total;

    /* ' ' eliminates row headings */
    table value_t1 = ' ', 
          value_t2 = ' '*total = ' '*sum=' '
    ;
run;
```

[image]

Or, you can turn it into a dataset:

```
proc transpose data = count_values 
               out  = count_values_tpose(drop=_NAME_);
    by value_t1;
    id value_t2;
    var total;
run;

data want;

    /* Set var order */
    length value_t1 $8.
           value1-value3 8.
    ;

    set count_values_tpose;
    array value[*] value1-value3;

    /* Set missing to 0 */
    do i = 1 to dim(value);
        if(value[i] = .) then value[i] = 0;
    end;

    rename value_t1 = values;

    drop i;
run;
```

Output:

```
values  value1  value2  value3
value1  0       1       1
value2  1       0       2
value3  1       2       0
```